# Regular Expression to split at number with 5 digits (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, parsing, csv

I've got the following problem.

I would like to split a string at a specific place. It's used to work with a csv file.

Following situation:

My CSV File goes like this:

```
33333|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'44444|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'11111|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
```

This means: I've got an ID at the beginning containing 5 digits, and I want to split this string and parse it into an array. I would like to use preg_split but how could I do this? I think of matching this part:

```
'44444|
```

And now the special wish: I would like to get this 5 digits into my array. So I want to get access to the part, that preg_split splices - is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are there no linebreaks in the file?

Comment: how the result array looks like?

Comment: @user2674202 also see, [if this helps](https://eval.in/192411)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
$str = "33333|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'44444|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'11111|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'";

$res = preg_split('/(\b\d{5}\|)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33333|
    [1] => 'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
    [2] => 44444|
    [3] => 'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
    [4] => 11111|
    [5] => 'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need regex here:

```
$array = explode('|', $your_csv_data);
```

will give you an array of the csv values. This of course only works if the pipe character cannot appear in the actual values. If you want the first item as the key for the dataset, you could do this:

```
$key = array_shift($array);
$list_of_csv_datas[$key] = $array;
```

Please correct me if I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to split the strings according to boundary which was present just before to the 5 digit number.

```
<?php
$string="33333|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'44444|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'11111|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'";
$regex = '~(?<!^)(?=\d{5})~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $string);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33333|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
    [1] => 44444|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
    [2] => 11111|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a parsing problem, not a regular expression problem. PHP has several built-in functions for parsing CSV data:

- [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
- [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

If you want to parse the entire row into an array, you can use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) like so:

```
$csv = "33333|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'44444|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'11111|'AB'|'01.01.2014'|'short'";
$csvArray = str_getcsv($csv, "|", "'");
print_r($csvArray);
```

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33333
    [1] => AB
    [2] => 01.01.2014
    [3] => short44444
    [4] => AB
    [5] => 01.01.2014
    [6] => short11111
    [7] => AB
    [8] => 01.01.2014
    [9] => short
)
```

Or, if you really just want the first column, you can just get everything on that line up until the first `|` delimiter:

```
echo substr($csv, 0, strpos($csv, '|'));
```